# Expectation Maximization in Matlab on Missing Data

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-mining, gaussian, expectation-maximization

I have to use **EM** to estimate the mean and covariance of the Gaussian distribution for each of the two classes. They have some missing attributes too.

Classes of each object is known. Therefore the problem basically reduces to fitting a gaussian model with missing element.

Which is the best library to use?

How is **ECM** Algorithm different from **EM** algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all.But I am using [ecmnmle](http://www.mathworks.in/help/toolbox/finance/f8-72885.html#f8-72907) for estimating parameters and then obtaining distribution of [marginals](http://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/viele/sta601s03/multnorm.pdf) which is used later in bayes classification. It works pretty fine with accuracies of 0.9 and 0.69 on 2 classes.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to the Statistics Toolbox, you can use the [GMDISTRIBUTION](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/gmdistributionclass.html) class to fit a Gaussian Mixture Model using the EM algorithm.

Here is an example:

```
%# sample dataset
load fisheriris
data = meas(:,1:2);
label = species;

%# fit GMM using EM
K = 2;
obj = gmdistribution.fit(data, K);

%# assign points to mixtures: argmax_k P(M(k)|data)
P = posterior(obj, data);
[~,mIDX] = max(P,[],2);

%# GMM components
obj.mu             %# means
obj.Sigma          %# covariances
obj.PComponents    %# mixture weights

%# visualize original data clusters
figure
gscatter(data(:,1), data(:,2), label)

%# visualize mixtures found
figure
gscatter(data(:,1), data(:,2), mIDX), hold on
ezcontour(@(x,y)pdf(obj,[x y]), xlim(), ylim())
```

[image]

If not, check out the excellent [Netlab Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2654-netlab), as it has GMM implementation.

Comment: I think this should be used if the classes are not known. Since I know the classes, it is better to fit gaussian to them separately. Hopefully latter would give better results in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [PMTK toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/pmtk3/source/browse/#svn/trunk/toolbox/LatentVariableModels/mixGauss%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

Here is the [EM implementation](http://code.google.com/p/pmtk3/source/browse/trunk/toolbox/LatentVariableModels/mixGauss/mixGaussMissingFitEm.m) (Fit a mixture of Gaussians where the data may have NaN entries)

Comment: ??? Undefined function or method 'process_options' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> mixGaussMissingFitEm at 12
[model.cpd.mu, model.cpd.Sigma, model.mixWeight, model.doMap, model.diagCov, EMargs] = ...